# No results using ::with() in Laravel using UUID´s (efficient-uuid)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

The current problem is, I use `efficient-uuid` for generating, casting and parseing uuids in Laravel for my Database. Normaly this worked good (after some tricky and A LOT of back and forth).
Honestly I currently always have problems with this "package".

The point is, when I make a request the return of Roles is empty (in both cases seen down). I think it is related to the package mentioned above.

Json:

```
    "user": {
        "user_id": "9b5afcea-82b6-4d8b-839c-08e628b1a197",
        "user_name": "User",
        "user_firstname": "T",
        "user_lastname": "T",
        "user_mail": "a@a.a",
        "user_phone": "+49",
        "user_verified": 0,
        "role": [],
        "roles": []
    }
```

Tried code:

```
$roles = Role::with('role')->whereUuid($db_token->user_id)->get();
```

or

```php
$user = User::with('roles')
    ->select(['*'])
    ->whereUuid($db_token->user_id)
    ->first();
```

`User.php`:

```php
public function roles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Role::class, 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
```

`Role.php`:

```php
public function role(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

- I know, the naming (role) isn´t very good...

Does someone has a hint, why this is so?

Edit:

The SQL Request is the following. Idk why it´s "`null?`":

```
"Execute","select * from `role` where `role`.`user_id` in (NULL)"
```

UserTable:

```
            $table->efficientUuid('user_id')->primary();
            $table->string('user_name', 64)->unique();
            $table->string('user_firstname', 128);
            $table->string('user_lastname', 64);
            $table->string('user_password', 128);
            $table->string('user_mail', 128)->unique();
            $table->string('user_phone', 20)->unique();
            $table->dateTime('user_birth_date');
            $table->boolean('user_verified')->default(false);
            $table->timestamp('user_created')->useCurrent();
          $table->timestamp('user_updated')->useCurrent()->useCurrentOnUpdate();
```

RoleTable:

```
            $table->efficientUuid('role_id')->primary();
            $table->efficientUuid('user_id')->index();
            $table->efficientUuid('region_id')->index();
            $table->tinyInteger('type');
            $table->timestamp('role_created')->useCurrent();
            $table->timestamp('role_updated')->useCurrent()->useCurrentOnUpdate();
            $table->unique(['user_id', 'region_id']);
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('user_id')->on('user')->
                onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('region_id')->references('region_id')->on('region')->
                onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
```

Comment: a Role has a relationship to itself? ... perhaps you should check the query log and paste the query that is being generated

Comment: Can you show us the structure of the users and roles table? Just primary and foreign keys.

Comment: `Role::with('role')` should that be `User::with('role')` or `Role::with('user')` maybe? Your relationship is `belongsTo(User::class)`, so calling `Role::with('role')` doesn't make a lot of sense here...

Comment: @TimLewis updated my question. Sorry was very unclear

Comment: Yeah, the name should indicate what is returned by the relationship; `role()` would be a `hasOne()` or `belongsTo()` using `Role::class`, `roles()` would be a `hasMany()` or `belongsToMany()` using `Role::class`, etc etc. That should really be renamed to `user()`, since it is a `belongsTo()` (single record or `null`) using `User::class`; try to write code that doesn't mislead. Also, a `Role <-> User` relationship is typically many-to-many, so a `Role` can have many `Users`, and a `User` can belong to many `Roles`. But these are just guidelines; adjust as required 

Comment: @TimLewis. Thank you. Changed that in my code. Also thank you for the `Role <-> User` relation. :). But as of my problem. Shouldn´t it be working or do I overlook something. 
I am very new to Laravel and their Eloquent-Builder System. Normally I would work with Joins, etc.

Comment: No problem! Those are just the typical naming and structure conventions, but changing them likely wouldn't fix what is going on with your code, sorry. (especially the many-to-many of User/Role, as that would require an additional pivot table). I haven't worked with UUIDs much, so I can't speak to how they would or wouldn't work, but Laravel's relationships _should_ be intelligent enough to look at the types and perform the queries necessary to construct them. Hopefully someone is able to recreate and help debug